# Setting Application Name in Android Devices

Tags: android, android-widget

I implemented a android project named 'vignesh', in which i had source package as com.example.learn.android. In my tab while uninstalling the app, its showing com.example.learn instead of project name alone. Please advice..

Comment: Can you please show me your manifest.xml file.?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify your application label in the `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application 
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  ...>

</application>
```

In the above example you have to define `app_name` in `res/strings.xml`

```
<string name="app_name">My app name</string>
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is not working in the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<application 
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    ...>

</application>
```

Look for the startup activity(the activity with the android.intent.action.MAIN & android.intent.category.LAUNCHER), example:

```
<activity
   android:name=".SplashScreen"
   android:label="com.example.learn"
   android:noHistory="true"
   android:screenOrientation="landscape"
   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
   <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

You probably have the android:label mentioned just like the example above. The strange thing is that Android takes your first activity's name (label) as app name (I don't know why).

If you just remove (or rename) the android:label="com.example.learn" line it should be ok. Removing the line ensures that the app will look for the android:label tag defined in the `<application>` part of the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: Thanks. but in my manifest i have android:label="@string/app_name"> where app_name in string.xml contains vignesh only